# Translation exception difference in EF Core's different Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, ef-core-3.1

I have used EF Core 3.1 and SQL Server 2017 in a project. In a repository method, I need to get the last row with some conditions like this:

```
var response = await _queryableDbSet.LastOrDefaultAsync(file =>
           (file.OriginalFileName + "." + file.Extension).ToLower() == fileName.ToLower());
```

but the above-mentioned code throws this exception:

> "The LINQ expression 'DbSet\n    .Where(f => (f.OriginalFileName + "." + f.Extension).ToLower() == __ToLower_0)\n    .LastOrDefault()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

By changing the query to be based on a simple where clause like this:

```
var response = await _queryableDbSet.Where(file => 
          (file.OriginalFileName + "." + file.Extension).ToLower() == fileName.ToLower())
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
     .Take(1)
     .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

everything works well.
I know the concept of query translation I think, but I don't know why different methods of a same library should result in different results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL comparisons are case insensitive already*.  There is no need (and in fact it's dangerous) to convert to lower case inside your where clause.

Comment: SQL has not LAST concepts. Therefore, we use descending and taking first one.

Answer (score 1):

*I* would avoid anything 'complicated' in a `.Where` clause.  It's much better to do simple comparisons (which Linq can easily translate).

```
var searchFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
var searchFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
var response = await _queryableDbSet.Where(file => 
      file.OriginalFileName == searchFileName && 
      file.Extension==searchFileExtension);
```

But, as @donggas90 points out, it's probably the `.LastOrDefault` that is your problem.